# Is a faithfully flat quasi-compact base change injective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $h\colon S' \rightarrow S$ be a faithfully flat quasi-compact morphism.
Let $f, g\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be morphisms of $S$-schemes.
Let $X', Y'$, and $f', g'$ be the base changes by $h$.
Suppose $f' = g'$.
Can we say $f = g$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and as with all your other recent questions, you can find the answer in EGA, SGA, textbooks such as the one by Görtz-Wedhorn, etc.. You should also have a look at FGA and in particular at Vistoli's notes on descent theory. It is a waste of time to ask these questions because they are all answered in the standard references.

If $f',g' : X_{S'} \to Y_{S'}$ are equal, then so are $f \circ p, g \circ p : X_{S'} \to X \to Y$. Since $p : X_{S'} \to X$ is faithfully flat and quasi-compact, hence an (effective) *epimorphism* by descent theory, it follows $f=g$.

Comment: [It is a waste of time to ask these questions because they are all answered in the standard references.]
Is there an *online* reference written in *English*?
I don't have an easy access to a university library.

Comment: The stacks project for example. And Vistoli's descent theory notes.

Comment: I checked the both.
There's not the proof in Vistoli's note.
I could not find the proof in the stacks project.
Could you tell me the page or proposition no.?

Comment: You certainly find that fpqc morphisms are effective epis and this is obviously equivalent to your question.

Comment: What about preservation of various properties of morphisms by fpqc base changes?

Comment: What about reading any of the references which I have mentioned??

Comment: There is not the proof in Vistoli's note.
I could not find the proof in the stack's project.
Could you tell me the page or proposition no.?